# response of requests.get() will change time format

Tags: python

For source of website, in `<view-source>`, it shows:

```
<a class="tip model-link inside">2019-5-28 19:47:57</a>
```

but when I call `requests.get()`, it returns:

```
<a class="tip model-link inside">May 28, 2019 7:47:57 PM</a>
```

How I can get the content in the first date format with requests response?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question and provide a link to the website you are attempting to get information from.

Comment: It's a CI website in internal network. no matter I use requests or urllib function, it response in format 'May 28, 2019 7:47:57 PM', but I need format '2019-5-28 19:47:57' as in view-source. I'm not sure it's a website issue or configuration in python requests.

Comment: Just a thought, but as detailed in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit), you may want to try emulating a browser visit with `requests` by using e.g. `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` where `headers` is the same User-Agent String as the browser you are visiting with to get the `2019-5-28 19:47:57` string.

Comment: Note that if you don't get the string you need, Python has facilities to turn strings such as e.g. `May 28, 2019 7:47:57` into date/time objects that can then be put into a different display format (this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) in particular has an answer that seems to fit your desired format, so you may wish to start there).

Comment: Here is a [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22128786/3395469) to the answer I mentioned.